# Volley - CancelAll() doesn't stop sending the request

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to completely stop volley request from sending the data, calling         `mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG)`
 method just stops the response from returning to the response handlers but sending the data process is still working at the background, i am sending a large byte[] file so once the user cancels the sending process, i want to interrupt the request and stop sending the data.
Can any one think of a workaround to overcome this problem ?

Comment: I guess you still receive the response for whatever data you have already sent

Comment: No, after calling  mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG) the response didn't return.

Comment: **Once the Request is in the Worker Thread already, you cannot interrupt it**. What will happen is; you will not receive the response though the bandwidth is already consumed. The workaround is to reverse engineer the Volley library.

Comment: I know, but there has to be some kind of a workaround to stop consuming the bandwidth, We've thought of disabling the internet and then enabling it back but that is a nasty solution :D There must be a better one.

Comment: Since the Volley library is opensource you can check what I mean. You can reverse engineer the cancellation method of Volley. The trick is just add a boolean flag for every bytes sent. That boolean flag will be your shutdown control. You don't need to disable the internet, many things will break :). BTW by worker thread what I mean is **Network Dispatcher Thread**.

Comment: Sounds like a solution to clone volley package and modify it to check for the cancel flag, but where exactly will i be able to check for the flag, and shutdown ? 
I've traced the code and reached to this point where body byte[] is sent to the DataOutputStream, check the addBodyIfExists method at this class 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/idea133/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HurlStack.java

Comment: Finally i could do it, i replaced "out.write(body);" with a loop that writes byte by byte and added the cancel check inside the loop, find it at the answer below. @Enzokie Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG)` method just stops the response from returning to the response handlers and keeps sending the request at the background, i could find a workaround to solve this issue by editing the volley library itself, here are the steps:

- Clone the volley library from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/
- Import it as a module to your project.
- Navigate to `com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack` java class, go to `addBodyIfExists()` method
- Replace this code:

  ```
  DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
  out.write(body);
  out.close();
  ```

with this code:

```
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    final int offset = 0;
    for (int i = offset; i < offset + body.length; i++) {
        //if at any time of sending the body, the mCancel boolean became true, then stop sending the request and break the loop
        if (request.isCanceled()) {
            Log.d("Tracing Request", "request.isCanceled()");
            out.close();
            break;
        }
        Log.d("Tracing Request", "Writing to DataOutputStream");
        out.write(body[i]);
    }
    out.close();
```

What i did was simply implementing here the code inside`out.write(body);` method but with adding the if condition to check if the request has been canceled then break out of the loop to stop sending the request.

Comment: Note that this solution will appear only on sending large data with the request.

Comment: Ok, Good Job :)